# Quickest Way For Me To Learn About Metropolis Hastings

Tags: metropolis-hastings

First of all, thanks for reading. I have a month to learn about Metropolis-Hastings with mathematical rigour, and i don't have other responsibilities. I am using second edition of "Monte Carlo Statistical Methods" by Robert and Casella that my professor recommended me. My teacher advised me to study chapter 6 (Markov Chains), then 7 (Metropolis-Hastings). I took undergraduate probability, which covered markov chains with transition matrices (discrete state space), and measure theory, which didn't cover Radon & Nikodym, product measures, etc. My first qustion is: Is this the optimal way to understand the algorithm rigorously? I am already having problems at the start of chapter 6. I didn't understand the rigour behind the transition kernels. Particularly the equation:\begin{align*}
P_x((X_1,\cdots,X_n)\in A_1\times\cdots A_n)= &\int_{A_1}\cdots\int_{A_{n-1}}K(y_{n-1},A_n)\\ &\times K(x,d(y_1))\cdots K(y_{n-2},d(y_{n-1}))
\end{align*} where $K:X\times B(X)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a transition kernel and $P_x(X_1\in A)=P(X_1\in A|x)$, i.e, starting from x, probability of $X_1$ being in $A$. What i understand is that $K(x,dy)=d\mu(y)$, if we let $\mu(A):=K(x,A)$. But $K(y_1,\cdot)$ is a different measure for each $y_1\in A_1$ .  So how can we integrate $K(x,d(y_1))\cdots K(y_{n-2},d(y_{n-1}))$ over $A_1\times\dots\times A_{n-1}$ ? Do i need to study measure theory a lot more to understand that?

Comment: Your best bet for a quick dive is to start with a study of the same algorithm in a discrete and finite state space.

Comment: Equation you are posting is only a more complicated way of saying that the probability of a certain sequence of states is the probability of all possible sequences that bring you to state $A_n$ at time n AND $A_{n+1}$  at time n+1 etc.

Comment: @ThreeDiag Does that mean i cannot learn the algorithm rigorously in a month?

Comment: Sorry, I favour measure theory as a rigorous way to attack such problems. I can provide a complete answer but not at the moment.

Comment: @taha ismet sevgili: Ben's answer is correct  ( IMHO. but everyone is different of course so Xi'an could be correct also for some people ) but as a pre-requisite to  doing what he said, I would read this first and understand it. http://web1.sph.emory.edu/users/hwu30/teaching/statcomp/papers/chibGreenbergMH.pdf

Comment: @ThreeDiag I think i understood what that integral calculates if it exists. What i didn't understand is the construction of this integral.

Comment: @Xi'an If you can provide a complete answer that shows me route, i would be so thankful.

Comment: @mlofton Thanks.

Comment: First, basic measure theory suffices to read these chapters and understand the mechanisms of Metropolis-Hastings math. Markov chain theory requires an understanding of conditioning, which in my opinion requires measure theory. In particular, the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm involves in continuous spaces both a point mass and a continuous transition kernel, which is rather awkward to handle without dominating measure. The equation you reproduce from [our book](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR) is one version of the Chapman–Kolmogorov equation. Which you can visualise by looking at the discrete case.

Comment: @Xi'an Wow, i didn't know i was talking to the author. This site is great. Thanks for the explanation, but can you specify the basic measure theory i need to sufficiently understand the material in chapter 6 and 7? Can you recommend me a book, or some chapters of a book? As i understand, if i know conditioning, basic measure theory (covering dominating measure) i will be able to read these chapters.

Answer (score 2):

> My first qustion is: Is this the optimal way to understand the algorithm rigorously?

It is not possible for any of us to explain the equations without seeing all the previous context, notational definitions, etc.  Regardless of this, I'm not a subscriber to the idea that you have to drench relatively simple ideas with a firehose of measure theory notation before they are "understood rigorously".  My experience is that this often makes statistical methods *less well understood*.  If you are having trouble with the measure theoretic presentation, see if you can go through the material and translate it back into regular statistical notation without the use of measures (i.e., using density functions, distribution functions, etc.).  Do this even if it entails a loss of generality, since you can always start from a less general presentation that makes sense to you, and then generalise from there using measures.  You might find that the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral is a good halfway method for this.

Another thing to bear in mind when learning algorithms is that it is far less important to understand the measure-theoretic details than it is to be able to actually construct and use the algorithm (and have some intuitive idea of why it works).  I'm a big fan of learning by doing, especially when dealing with algorithms.  My recommendation would be to set aside the measure theory work for a while and muddle through an attempt to program the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm for a simple problem where you can compare it to a known solution (i.e., a problem where the algebra yields a closed form integral).  Once you have done this you will be able to see why it is working and this will assist your later mathematical analysis.  Seperately from that, it will also give you more holistic applied knowledge of the method.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. As i understand, you are suggesting that i should program Metropolis-Hastings as a solution of a problem, and then return to measure theory. After i finish an implementation, do i only need to know about the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral, or what else i need to know exacly to be able to grasp the material in the book?